# Python history command has no output

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I'm trying to get the output of the `history` command in python, but it returns nothing. When I run it in the terminal it returns my last commands. I'm using Mac OS.

```
import subprocess

command = 'history'

# Execute the command using a shell
result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

# Check the result
if result.returncode == 0:
    print("Command executed successfully!")
    print("Output:")
    print(result.stdout)
else:
    print("Error executing command:")
    print(result.stderr)
```

Output:

```
Command executed successfully!
Output:
```

Comment: `history` returns the history of commands you have executed in a shell session.  But `subprocess.run()` starts a _brand new_ shell session, where no commands have yet been executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple explanation of what I know about it:

When you run the `history` command via `subprocess` in Python, it typically returns nothing because `history` is not an actual command like `ls` or `cat`, but rather a shell builtin that's available in your terminal (like bash or zsh). This means `history` works within the context of a shell session to list the commands you've executed in that session, and it relies on the environment of the shell to function.

When you execute `subprocess.run` with `shell=True`, it starts a new shell session for that command, which doesn't have the same command history as your interactive terminal session. Therefore, the `history` command doesn't return anything because, from the perspective of that new shell session, no commands have been executed.

If you want to access the command history in a script, you might consider reading the history file directly. For bash, this is typically `~/.bash_history`, and for zsh, it's `~/.zsh_history`. You can read this file from Python to get the command history. Here's how you could do it for bash:

```py
history_file = '~/.bash_history'

# Expand the path to the user's home directory
full_path = os.path.expanduser(history_file)

try:
    with open(full_path, 'r') as file:
        history = file.readlines()
    print("Command executed successfully!")
    print("Output:")
    for command in history:
        print(command.strip())
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error reading history file: {e}")
```

Adjust the `history_file` variable if you're using a different shell.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is correct as there will not be any history. What you are doing in the Python program is starting a new shell to run whatever command(s) you pass to it. And in your case the very first command that that shell executes is **history**.

Comment: Is there a way to run the command as suer in Mac OS

Comment: It rather depends on what the OS allows. Generally speaking su/sudo are restricted to interactive shells, and in your case the generated shell is not interactive. Maybe you should explain exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OSX, I have two shells, bash and zsh. If you `echo $SHELL` in the terminal, you will find out the active shell. It will most likely produce an output like /bin/zsh. Note if you cd into /bin, you will also find /bin/bash. Therefore, to ensure you get the history of the active shell, you can use the following code. I just tested this and verified it produced the current active shell history in OSX:

```
import os

shell = os.environ["SHELL"]
print(shell)

shell_map = { "/bin/zsh" : ".zsh_history", "/bin/bash" : ".bash_history" }

for history in open(os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], shell_map[shell])):
    print(history, end='')
```

Answer (score -1):

`history` is a bash builtin, and is intended for interactive use.

You might prefer to directly open `Path('~/.bash_history').expanduser()`
and read its contents.

Comment: Not limited to bash

Comment: OP is free to specify the shell(s) of interest, if desired.

Comment: My point is that your answer is limited to bash - e.g., it wouldn't work if OP's default/preferred shell is, for example, zsh

Comment: I don't use zsh, not even on my mac laptop, so it's uninteresting. @CtrlZ, you are free to guess about the Business Domain problem that OP is actually trying to solve, propose a solution satisfying that use case across `tcsh`, `ash`, and other shells of interest to OP, and test the solution across all relevant shell variants. I'm not stopping you. Alternatively, we could offer something that is Good Enough, clearly relevant for the problem as described, and invite OP to engage in constructive dialog which reveals what their [true problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) actually is.